# HttpException in ASP.NET MVC with EntityFramework and JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to make a select on the database. But I get following error (only the first rows of the error):

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below

[HttpException (0x80004005): Server cannot set content type after HTTP headers have been sent.]
   System.Web.HttpResponse.set_ContentType(String value) +9752569
   System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.set_ContentType(String value) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +177
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +27
```

A part of my DBcontroller:

```
string sql = @"exec [results].[GetNewResults] '" + Sources + @"', '" + Searchstring + @"', '" + username + @"', '" + sessionid + @"'";
        var result = dbcontext_hke.Database.SqlQuery<UnifiedResultset>(sql);

if (results == null)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("results is null");
    return Json(null);
}

Debug.WriteLine("results isn't null");
Debug.WriteLine(results);
return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

A part of my js:

```
var url = $('#initialrequest').val();
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {sources, searchstring},
    type: 'POST',
})
.success(function (result) {
for (var i = 0; i <= (9); i++) {
    try {
        console.log("lenght of result is :" + result.length);
        add_error(result);
        console.log("result is : " + result);
        add_result(result[i].header, result[i].source, result[i].subsource, result[i].description);
    } catch (err) {
        add_error();
    }
 })
.error(function (xhr, status) {
    $('#error').append(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
});
```

Basically after some research I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908707/asp-net-jquery-ajax-post-returns-data-but-within-a-401-response) with that code as a solution for a (maybe) similar problem:

```
this.Context.Response.Write(response);
this.Context.Response.Flush();
```

May anyone explain to me what is going on there and how I can fix it (or modify the code of the other solution)?

**EDIT1:** I have ensured that the controller get's the information. So the error might be at the communication between controller and js. Any ideas?

**EDIT2:** Also adding

```
Response.BufferOutput = true;
```

at the Index() of the HomeController and the DBController doesn't change anything.

**EDIT3:** I identified that the Problem is with the JSON in the return. If I return a different type, it works fine. Any ideas why this happens and how to fix it?

**EDIT4:** The reason my code doesn't work is because the command

```
var result = dbcontext_hke.Database.SqlQuery<UnifiedResultset>(sql);
```

doesn't execute immediately I think. If I want to see what's inside result with Debug.WriteLine(result) I only get the plain sql command. Ideas?

Comment: You can find very detailed discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383169/server-cannot-set-status-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-iis7-5). I believe other parts of your code cause this behavior, not the one you have showed. The only suspect I see is `return Json(null)` - not sure how this works exactly

Comment: I'm not quite sure - the discussion is good to get a overview, but I really don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Andrei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/728795/andrei) was right - there was another line that caused this error. 
As [stephbu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12702/stephbu) mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383169/server-cannot-set-status-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-iis7-5) as item 3: "the stream was unbuffered forcing the response headers to get written before the markup writing could begin."

This scenario was caused by the line

```
Response.Flush();
```

that was above the DB controller code I've mentioned